# How to auto add where clause when joining 2 tables in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Context: Have 2 table with 1:1 relation want to add a where clause on table join tried to achieve this by adding ***@WhereJoinTable(clause = "addressType = 'STORE_ADDRESS'")*** annotation but its not working in my case

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(max = 500)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "store", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "addressType = 'STORE_ADDRESS'")
    private Address address;

    public Store() {
    }
}
```

,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private A store;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "address_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StoreAddressType addressType;

    public StoreAddress() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@WhereJoinTable` annotation is used when an association table is used. You don't need an association table for a 1:1 relationship.

The `@Where` annotation is applied in your target entity.

That's why you should try to use the `@Where` annotation instead of the `@WhereJoinTable` annotation . You can do this as follows.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(max = 500)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "store", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Where(clause = "addressType = 'STORE_ADDRESS'")
    private Address address;

    public Store() {
    }
}
```

Comment: checked this too not working in my case checked the generated query where clause is not added in query

Comment: Please, try remove `optional=false` and change `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` please.